# Por que meu ManagedBean não recebe o valor passado na pagina xhtml?

Tags: java, jsf, aplicação-web, primefaces

Estou com erro daqueles que já não consigo mais visualizar o problema e talvez, vocês "olhando de fora" consigam me ajudar.

A questão é simples, não estou recebendo o valor de um input da minha view no ManagedBean. Este input:

```
<p:inputMask value="#{cadastroClienteMB.cpffind}"
                            mask="999-999-999-99" />
```

Este campo cpffind não está sendo atribuído do outro lado. Na verdade debugando, descobri que ele nem chama o método set do atributo

Seguem a view e o ManagedBean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:adm="http://github.com/adminfaces"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="title">
    Cadastro de cliente
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="body">
    <f:metadata>
    </f:metadata>


    <h:form id="form" prependId="false">
        <p:focus />


        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">



                <p:separator />
                <p:tabView>
                    <p:tab title="Informações">

                        <p:panel header="Informações">



                            <div class="ui-fluid">
                                <p:panelGrid id="capaPanel">
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-6">

                                            <p:outputLabel value="Categoria" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.categoria}">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{categoriaMB.categorias}"
                                                    var="categoria" itemLabel="#{categoria.dscategori}"
                                                    itemValue="#{categoria}" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-6">
                                            <div class="input-group margin">
                                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <p:commandButton update="titularDetail"
                                                        oncomplete="PF('titularDialog').show()"
                                                        title="Você pode clicar para pesquisar"
                                                        class="btn btn-primary" icon="fa fa-search"
                                                        value="Titular" />
                                                </div>

                                                <p:inputMask mask="9999-999999-9"
                                                    value="#{cadastroClienteMB.habilitacaodotitular}"
                                                    type="text" class="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="Habilitação do titular" aria-label=""
                                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Nome do cliente" for="nome" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nmcliente}" id="nome" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Nome social" for="nome-social" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nmsocial}"
                                                id="nome-social" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Nascimento" for="nascimento" />
                                            <p:calendar
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dtnascimen}"
                                                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="nascimento">
                                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/aaaa"
                                                    timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
                                            </p:calendar>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Sexo" for="sexo" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.cdsexo}" id="sexo">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Masculino" itemValue="0" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Feminino" itemValue="1" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Parentesco" for="parentesco" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dsparentsc}"
                                                id="parentesco">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                                                <f:selectItem
                                                    itemLabel="Cônjuge/Companheiro de união estável"
                                                    itemValue="CONJUGE" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Viúvo união civil/União estável"
                                                    itemValue="VIUVO_UNIAO_CIVIL_ESTAVEL" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Filho" itemValue="FILHO" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Neto" itemValue="NETO" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Enteado" itemValue="ENTEADO" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pessoa sob guarda"
                                                    itemValue="PESSOA_SOB_GUARDA" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pai" itemValue="PAI" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mãe" itemValue="MAE" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Padastro" itemValue="PADASTRO" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Madastra" itemValue="MADASTRA" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Avô" itemValue="AVO_HOMEM" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Avó" itemValue="AVO_MULHER" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pai" itemValue="PAI" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tutor" itemValue="TUTOR" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Estado Civil" for="estado-civil" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.cdestcivil}"
                                                id="estado-civil">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Solteiro" itemValue="0" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Casado" itemValue="1" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Viúvo" itemValue="2" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Divorciado" itemValue="3" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Separado" itemValue="4" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="União estável" itemValue="5" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Dependentes" for="dependentes" />
                                            <p:spinner value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nudepend}"
                                                id="dependentes">
                                            </p:spinner>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="CPF" for="cpf" />
                                            <p:inputMask value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nucpf}"
                                                mask="999.999.999-99" id="cpf" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </div>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Identidade">
                        <p:panel header="Identidade">
                            <div class="ui-fluid">
                                <p:panelGrid id="capaPanel2">
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="tipo-rg" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.tipoidentidade}"
                                                id="tipo-rg">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Carteira de identidade"
                                                    itemValue="RG" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Carteira nacional de habilitação"
                                                    itemValue="CNH" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Carteira de registro profissional"
                                                    itemValue="CARTEIRA_PROFISSIONAL" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Carteira de trabalho"
                                                    itemValue="CTPS" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certidão de nascimento"
                                                    itemValue="CERTIDAO_NASCIMENTO" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Certificado de reservista"
                                                    itemValue="CERTIFICADO_RESERVISTA" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Passaporte" itemValue="PASSAPORTE" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Registro nacional de estrangeiro"
                                                    itemValue="RNE" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Número" for="numero-rg" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nureggeral}"
                                                id="numero-rg" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Órgão emissor" for="orgao-rg" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.idorgemirg}"
                                                id="orgao-rg" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Data de emissão" for="data-rg" />
                                            <p:calendar value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dtemirg}"
                                                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="data-rg">
                                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/aaaa"
                                                    timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
                                            </p:calendar>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Informações complementares"
                                                for="info-complementares" />
                                            <p:inputTextarea
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.compidentidade}"
                                                id="info-complementares" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Escolaridade" for="escolaridade" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.cdnivel}"
                                                id="escolaridade">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sem escolaridade" itemValue="1" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Analfabeto" itemValue="2" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Alfabetizado" itemValue="3" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ensino fundamental incompleto"
                                                    itemValue="5" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ensino fundamental" itemValue="4" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ensino médio incompleto"
                                                    itemValue="6" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ensino médio" itemValue="7" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Superior incompleto" itemValue="8" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Superior" itemValue="9" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pós graduação" itemValue="10" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pós graduação incompleta"
                                                    itemValue="11" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Última série" for="ultima-serie" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nuultserie}"
                                                disabled="true" id="ultima-serie" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.isestudante}"
                                                itemLabel="Ainda estudante" />
                                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cadastroClienteMB.ispcd}"
                                                itemLabel="Pessoa com deficiência" />
                                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.isemancipado}"
                                                itemLabel="Emancipado" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Nome do pai" for="nome-pai" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nmpai}"
                                                id="nome-pai" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Nome da mãe" for="nome-mae" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nmmae}"
                                                id="nome-mae" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Naturalidade" for="naturalidade" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dsnatural}"
                                                id="naturalidade" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Nacionalidade" for="nacionalidade" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dsnacional}"
                                                id="nacionalidade" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </div>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Endereço">
                        <p:panel header="Endereço">
                            <div class="ui-fluid">
                                <p:panelGrid id="capaPanel3">
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-2">
                                            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-male"
                                                value="Utilizar endereço do titular"
                                                class="btn btn-primary">

                                            </p:commandButton>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-6">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Logradouro" for="logradouro" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.endereco_dslogradou}"
                                                id="logradouro" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-1">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Número" for="numero" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.endereco_nuimovel}"
                                                id="numero" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-6">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Complemento" for="complemento" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.endereco_dscomplemen}"
                                                id="complemento" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="ui-g-2">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Bairro" for="bairro" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.endereco_dsbairro}"
                                                id="bairro" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-1">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="UF" for="uf" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cadastroClienteMB.sigla_estados}"
                                                id="uf">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UF" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                                <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{estado.sigla}"
                                                    itemValue="#{estado.sigla}" var="estado"
                                                    value="#{cadastroClienteMB.getEstados()}" />
                                                <p:ajax process="@this"
                                                    listener="#{cadastroClienteMB.findAllEstates()}"
                                                    event="change" update="cidade" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Cidade" for="cidade" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="cidade"
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.municipio}">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroClienteMB.municipios}"
                                                    var="municipio" itemLabel="#{municipio.dsmunicip}"
                                                    itemValue="#{municipio}" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="ui-g-4">

                                            <div class="input-group margin">
                                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <p:commandButton class="btn btn-primary"
                                                        icon="fa fa-search" value="CEP" />
                                                </div>

                                                <input
                                                    value="#{cadastroClienteMB.endereco_nucep}
                                                    "
                                                    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CEP"
                                                    aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </div>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="Informações profissionais">
                        <p:panel header="Informações profissionais">
                            <div class="ui-fluid">
                                <p:panelGrid id="capaPanel4">
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-2">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Situação profissional"
                                                for="situacao-profissional" />
                                            <p:selectOneMenu
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.situprof}"
                                                id="situacao-profissional">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Sem informação" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Empregado" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Aposentado" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Estagiário" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="Jovem aprendiz" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="Licenciado" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="6" itemLabel="Desempregado" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="7" itemLabel="Falecido" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-6">

                                            <div class="input-group margin">
                                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <p:commandButton class="btn btn-primary"
                                                        icon="fa fa-search" value="Empresa" />
                                                </div>

                                                <input value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.empresa}"
                                                    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Empresa"
                                                    aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Descrição do cargo"
                                                for="descricao-cargo" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dscargo}"
                                                id="descricao-cargo" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-1">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Valor da renda" for="valor-renda" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.vlrenda}"
                                                id="valor-renda" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Data Admissão" for="data-admissao" />
                                            <p:calendar
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dtadmissao}"
                                                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="data-admissao">
                                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/aaaa"
                                                    timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
                                            </p:calendar>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Data Demissão" for="data-demissao" />
                                            <p:calendar
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.dtdemissao}"
                                                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="data-demissao">
                                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/aaaa"
                                                    timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
                                            </p:calendar>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Carteira profissional"
                                                for="carteira-profissional" />
                                            <p:inputMask value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nuctps}"
                                                id="carteira-profissional" mask="999.9999/99999" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="PIS/PASEP" for="pis-pasep" />
                                            <p:inputMask
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.nupispasep}"
                                                id="pis-pasep" mask="999.99999.99.9" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Valor da renda familiar"
                                                for="renda-familiar" />
                                            <p:inputText
                                                value="#{cadastroClienteMB.clientela.vlrendafam}"
                                                id="renda-familiar" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </div>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>

                    <p:tab title="Contatos">
                        <p:panel header="Contatos">
                            <div class="ui-fluid">
                                <p:panelGrid id="capaPanel6">
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-1">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Celular" />
                                            <p:inputMask value="#{cadastroClienteMB.celular}"
                                                mask="(99)99999-9999" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-1">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="Telefone fixo" />
                                            <p:inputMask value="#{cadastroClienteMB.fixo}"
                                                mask="(99)9999-9999" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-g">
                                        <div class="ui-g-4">
                                            <p:outputLabel value="E-mail" />
                                            <p:inputText value="#{cadastroClienteMB.email}" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                            </div>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p:panel id="titularDetail" style="text-align:center;">
            <p:dialog width="800" height="300" responsive="true"
                appendTo="@(body)" closable="false" header="Busca de titular"
                widgetVar="titularDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
                hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="capaPanel15">
                    <p:outputLabel value="CPF do titular" />
                    <p:inputMask value="#{cadastroClienteMB.cpffind}"
                        mask="999-999-999-99" />

                    <p:outputLabel value="Habilitação do titular" />
                    <p:inputMask mask="9999-999999-9" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton process="@this" update="table_resp"
                    actionListener="#{cadastroClienteMB.findTitularByCpf()}"
                    styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar" />
                <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('titularDialog').hide();"
                    styleClass="btn btn-danger" value="Fechar" />
                <p:dataTable value="#{cadastroClienteMB.responsavel}"
                    var="responsavel" selection="true" emptyMessage="Sem responsáveis"
                    id="table_resp">
                    <p:column headerText="Nome">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{responsavel.nmcliente}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="CPF">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{responsavel.nucpf}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Nome da mãe">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{responsavel.nmmae}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:dialog>
        </p:panel>


    </h:form>


</ui:define>
```

```
package br.com.sescsc.central.mb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import br.com.sescsc.central.model.Categoria;
import br.com.sescsc.central.model.Clientela;
import br.com.sescsc.central.model.Enderecos;
import br.com.sescsc.central.model.Estados;
import br.com.sescsc.central.model.Municipio;
import br.com.sescsc.central.service.Service;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CadastroClienteMB implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Clientela clientela = new Clientela();
    private Integer habilitacaodotitular;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private boolean isestudante;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private boolean ispcd;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private boolean isemancipado;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String sigla_estados;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private Municipio municipio;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String celular;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String fixo;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String email;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String endereco_dslogradou;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String endereco_nuimovel;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String endereco_dscomplemen;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String endereco_dsbairro;
    // colocar na hora de persistir
    private String endereco_nucep;

    private String cpffind;

    private Clientela responsavel;

    public Clientela getResponsavel() {
        return responsavel;
    }

    public void setResponsavel(Clientela responsavel) {
        this.responsavel = responsavel;
    }

    public String getCpffind() {
        return cpffind;
    }

    public void setCpffind(String cpffind) {
        this.cpffind = cpffind;
    }

    public String getEndereco_nuimovel() {
        return endereco_nuimovel;
    }

    public void setEndereco_nuimovel(String endereco_nuimovel) {
        this.endereco_nuimovel = endereco_nuimovel;
    }

    public String getEndereco_dscomplemen() {
        return endereco_dscomplemen;
    }

    public void setEndereco_dscomplemen(String endereco_dscomplemen) {
        this.endereco_dscomplemen = endereco_dscomplemen;
    }

    public String getEndereco_dsbairro() {
        return endereco_dsbairro;
    }

    public void setEndereco_dsbairro(String endereco_dsbairro) {
        this.endereco_dsbairro = endereco_dsbairro;
    }

    public String getEndereco_nucep() {
        return endereco_nucep;
    }

    public void setEndereco_nucep(String endereco_nucep) {
        this.endereco_nucep = endereco_nucep;
    }

    public String getEndereco_dslogradou() {
        return endereco_dslogradou;
    }

    public void setEndereco_dslogradou(String endereco_dslogradou) {
        this.endereco_dslogradou = endereco_dslogradou;
    }

    public String getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getFixo() {
        return fixo;
    }

    public void setFixo(String fixo) {
        this.fixo = fixo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Municipio getMunicipio() {
        return municipio;
    }

    public void setMunicipio(Municipio municipio) {
        this.municipio = municipio;
    }

    private List<Municipio> municipios;

    public List<Municipio> getMunicipios() {
        return municipios;
    }

    public void setMunicipios(List<Municipio> municipios) {
        this.municipios = municipios;
    }

    public String getSigla_estados() {
        return sigla_estados;
    }

    public void setSigla_estados(String sigla_estados) {
        this.sigla_estados = sigla_estados;
    }

    public boolean isIsemancipado() {
        return isemancipado;
    }

    public void setIsemancipado(boolean isemancipado) {
        this.isemancipado = isemancipado;
    }

    public boolean isIspcd() {
        return ispcd;
    }

    public void setIspcd(boolean ispcd) {
        this.ispcd = ispcd;
    }

    public boolean isIsestudante() {
        return isestudante;
    }

    public void setIsestudante(boolean isestudante) {
        this.isestudante = isestudante;
    }

    public Integer getHabilitacaodotitular() {
        return habilitacaodotitular;
    }

    public void setHabilitacaodotitular(Integer habilitacaodotitular) {
        this.habilitacaodotitular = habilitacaodotitular;
    }

    public CadastroClienteMB() {

    }

    public Clientela getClientela() {
        return clientela;
    }

    public void setClientela(Clientela clientela) {
        this.clientela = clientela;
    }

    public void inserirCliente() {

    }

    public List<Estados> getEstados() {
        return Estados.getList();
    }

    public List<Municipio> findAllEstates() {
        Service service = new Service();
        System.out.println("Estado Selecionado: " + this.getSigla_estados());
        if (this.getSigla_estados() != null) {
            String retorno = service.getEndpoint("municipio/findAllMunicipioFrom", this.getSigla_estados());
            List<Municipio> listaMunicipios = new Gson().fromJson(retorno, new TypeToken<List<Municipio>>() {
            }.getType());
            this.municipios = listaMunicipios;
            return listaMunicipios;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Clientela findTitularByCpf() {
        System.out.println("chamou findCPF: " + this.getCpffind());
        Service service = new Service();

//      if(this.getCpf_titular_find()==null || this.getCpf_titular_find().equals("")) {
//          this.setCpf_titular_find("11111111111");
//      }

        String retorno = service.getEndpoint("clientela/findOneClienteCPF=", this.getCpffind());
        Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").create();
        Clientela responsavelvindo = g.fromJson(retorno, Clientela.class);
        // Clientela responsavelvindo = new Gson().fromJson(retorno, Clientela.class);
        this.responsavel = responsavelvindo;
        return responsavelvindo;

    }

}
```

Comment: Tenta usar dentro do inputMask o process="@this" ou @form

Comment: Queira [edit] o post reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema. Da forma como está fica dependendo de uma análise extensa que não se encaixa bem na objetividade requerida pelo site.

Comment: O problema era que o inputDialog deve estar dentro de outro form